# npm install <node_module> --save not updating dependencies

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

```
    <=== To anyone experiencing the same issue reinstalling the computer works ===>
```

I've had to reinstall my computer, had to reinstall Node and NPM and don't know what's gone wrong and it's driving me crazy.

I'm on a Windows 10 64-bit computer, I run `npm init` and it works fine. I can install dependencies with no trouble, both locally and globally, but using `npm install <node_module> --save` doesn't update my `package.json` file with dependencies.

I've reinstalled both npm and node, no change.
I've tried running cmd as administrator, nothing.
I've restarted the computer too, still nothing.

If anyone knows how to solve this, please help. I'm desperate!

Update #1: when installing some modules I see that they create .cmd files in my project folder, if this is a clue, haven't experienced that before

Update #2:
Just created a fresh install using `npm init` and then tried `npm install express --save` and this is the package.json file:

```
  {  
    "name": "test",  
    "version": "1.0.0",  
    "description": "",  
    "main": "index.js",  
    "scripts": {  
      "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"  
    },  
    "keywords": [],  
    "author": "",  
    "license": "ISC"  
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure you are installing to the right place? Right project?

Comment: If I'm looking at the correct package.json file? Yes, absolutely. Probably checked 10 times, if not more.

Comment: Can I see your package.json?

Comment: @AndrewLi Updated the question

Comment: This doesn't makes a sense. Maybe the permission to the npm the to write the file?!

Comment: Maybe check windows permissions, you might have append but not update rights on this file.  Can you modify file manually?.  You said re-install computer was this a fresh install, is the directory you installing from old install?

Comment: @LucasCosta Nope, just looked at properties and it's free for anyone to read and write what ever on it.

Comment: @Keith Permissions look alright in the properties window. I can change whatever I want using whatever kind of editor I like, nothing pops up warning me at least. My computer automatically updated itself which crashed windows forcing me to reinstall the whole computer. I opted to save my files, but looks like I'll be forced to reinstall with a completely whiped computer instead.

Comment: Any easy check, try doing it on an FAT formatted drive, if you have no spare HD to format to FAT, just try doing on a USB pen.  NTFS permissions can sometimes be funky..

Comment: Can you run the following commands and provide the output? `C:\>mkdir test_node`

`C:\>cd test_node`

`C:\test_node>npm init`

`C:\test_node>npm install color --save`

`C:\test_node>type package.json`

Comment: @David, If you are still experiencing the issue, please run the commands from my previous comment and post the results in your question.

Comment: @ppovoski that's what I have above, except only "test" instead of "test_node" and "express" instead of "color".

However, now I've reinstalled a fresh copy of Windows and everything works like it's suppose to. So I'm attributing this to the error forcing me to reinstall from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by completely wiping and reinstalling my computer. If there's another fix to this I don't know it, but this is one fix... The nuclear way.

Answer (score -1):

Just a suggestion, you may try to add "sudo" before your command.

Comment: I'm on windows... There's no such thing as "sudo", as I said, I've tried running it as administrator (the Windows equivalent of "sudo")

Comment: Oh, sorry. I never use windows for developing. So I don't know it's without 'sudo'.